# ESP8266 Cant to connect to client

Tags: c, esp8266

I have a very simple mysql database, which can receive new values via a simple command:

```
 http://7751b6b1.ngrok.io/ethernet/data.php?movement=test
```

If I enter that in my browser "test" gets write to the databank. Now I want to write to that database via my ESP8266:

```
 #include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
//General Definition

const char server[] = "https://7751b6b1.ngrok.io";
 //localhost into server via ngrok
const char* MY_SSID = "Gastzugang";
const char* MY_PWD =  "12345678";
String mov; //create Text string
WiFiClient client; //Create Wifi client

//Setup
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("Connecting to "+*MY_SSID);
 WiFi.begin(MY_SSID, MY_PWD);
Serial.println("going into wl connect");
 int PIR_output=16; // output of pir sensor 
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) //not connected,  ...waiting to 
 connect
 {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
 }
 Serial.println("wl connected");
 Serial.println("");
 Serial.println("Credentials accepted! Connected to wifi\n ");
 Serial.println("");
 }

 void loop() {
 if(digitalRead(16) == HIGH) // reading the data from the pir sensor
 {
 mov = "1";
 Serial.println("1");
 }
 else {
 mov = "0" ;
 Serial.println("0");
 }

 if (client.connect(server, 8095)) { //Connecting at the IP address and port

 Serial.println("connected to server");
 WiFi.printDiag(Serial);
 client.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?");
 //Connecting and Sending values to database
 client.print("movement=");
 client.print(mov);
 client.stop();
 }
 else {
 // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
 Serial.println("connection failed");
 }
 delay(50);
 }
```

Sensor reading and Wifi connection works wells but I end up with "connection failed".

Can anyone spot the error?

Edit: Updated Code

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
//General Definition
const char server[] = "http://b90e9280.ngrok.io"; //localhost?
const char* MY_SSID = "Gastzugang";
const char* MY_PWD =  "12345678";
String mov; //create Text string
WiFiClient client; //Create Wifi client
//Setup
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println("Connecting to "+*MY_SSID);
WiFi.begin(MY_SSID, MY_PWD);
Serial.println("going into wl connect");
int PIR_output=16; // output of pir sensor 
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) //not connected,  ...waiting to 
connect
{
   delay(1000);
   Serial.print(".");
 }
Serial.println("wl connected");
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Credentials accepted! Connected to wifi\n ");
Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
//here sensor reading einfügen

if (client.connect(server, 80)) { //Connecting at the IP address and port
Serial.println("connected to server");
WiFi.printDiag(Serial);
client.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?"); //making a http request
Serial.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?");
//Connecting and Sending values to database
if(digitalRead(16) == HIGH) // reading the data from the pir sensor
{
 mov = "1";
client.println("movement=1");
Serial.println("movement=1");
 }
 else {
  mov = "0" ;
  client.println("movement=0");
  Serial.println("movement=0");
  }
  delay(5000);
  client.stop();
}
else {
// if you didn't get a connection to the server:
Serial.println("connection failed");
}
delay(50);
}
```

Comment: the docs https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClientConnect say server name not http url (even though its call url)

Comment: you use http in the browser, but https on the esp, and that's not how you do https on ESPs. use plain http and you're golden, or take the time to setup a cert fingerprint and jump through the other https hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation isn't clear on this, but `WiFiClient` only supports `http`, not `https`.

It's great that you're using `https`! But you'll need to use `WiFiClientSecure` instead of `WifiClient`.

You'll most likely want to verify the server's identity once you connect. You'll do that using the `verify` method on the `client` object. To do that you'll need to know the fingerprint of the certificate the web server uses.

So your code would look something like this:

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
//General Definition

#define SERVER_FINGERPRINT "C0 5D 08 5E E1 3E E0 66 F3 79 27 1A CA 1F FC 09 24 11 61 62"

const char server[] = "https://7751b6b1.ngrok.io";
 //localhost into server via ngrok
const char* MY_SSID = "Gastzugang";
const char* MY_PWD =  "12345678";
String mov; //create Text string
WiFiClientSecure client; //Create Wifi client

//Setup
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("Connecting to "+*MY_SSID);
 WiFi.begin(MY_SSID, MY_PWD);
Serial.println("going into wl connect");
 int PIR_output=16; // output of pir sensor 
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) //not connected,  ...waiting to 
 connect
 {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
 }
 Serial.println("wl connected");
 Serial.println("");
 Serial.println("Credentials accepted! Connected to wifi\n ");
 Serial.println("");
 }

 void loop() {
 if(digitalRead(16) == HIGH) // reading the data from the pir sensor
 {
 mov = "1";
 Serial.println("1");
 }
 else {
 mov = "0" ;
 Serial.println("0");
 }

 if (client.connect(server, 8095)) { //Connecting at the IP address and port

 Serial.println("connected to server");

 if (client.verify(SERVER_FINGERPRINT, host)) {
   Serial.println("certificate matches");
  } else {
   Serial.println("certificate doesn't match");
 }

 WiFi.printDiag(Serial);
 client.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?");
 //Connecting and Sending values to database
 client.print("movement=");
 client.print(mov);
 client.stop();
 }
 else {
 // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
 Serial.println("connection failed");
 }
 delay(50);
 }
```

The three important changes are:
- defining `client` to be `WiFiClientSecure` rather than `WiFiClient`
- adding a call to `client.verify` after the connection succeeds
- providing a constant server finger print to compare with

The fingerprint I provided won't work with your server. You'll need to find its fingerprint yourself. You can do this going to it with a web browser like Chrome and clicking on the "Secure" field in the address bar (in Chrome's case). Click on "Certificate", then expand "Details" in the view of the certificate. Scroll to the end and you'll see two fingerprints, SHA-256 and SHA-1. Copy the SHA-1 fingerprint and provide it as a string like the `SERVER_FINGERPRINT` I included.

You can skip verifying the certificate if you want but then you won't be certain you're actually connecting to the real server instead of a server impersonating it.

There's more info on `WiFiClientSecure` at [Client Secure](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/esp8266wifi/client-secure-examples.rst), including another example of how to find a server's fingerprint under Windows.

If you run into problems, I'd recommend stripping your program down to just the basics - `WiFi` connect and then `WiFiClientSecure`; don't worry about the PIR sensor or anything else. Once you get the stripped down version working with your server, transpose the changes you made back into the real program you're trying to get working.

*Update*

For your revised code, it's written right now as:

```
client.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?"); //making a http request
Serial.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?");
//Connecting and Sending values to database
if(digitalRead(16) == HIGH) // reading the data from the pir sensor
{
 mov = "1";
client.println("movement=1");
Serial.println("movement=1");
 }
 else {
  mov = "0" ;
  client.println("movement=0");
  Serial.println("movement=0");
  }
  delay(5000);
  client.stop();
}
```

Try:

```
client.print("Get /ethernet/data.php?"); //making a http request
Serial.println("Get /ethernet/data.php?");
//Connecting and Sending values to database
if(digitalRead(16) == HIGH) // reading the data from the pir sensor
{
 mov = "1";
client.print("movement=1");
Serial.println("movement=1");
 }
 else {
  mov = "0" ;
  client.print("movement=0");
  Serial.println("movement=0");
  }

  client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: 7751b6b1.ngrok.io");

  delay(5000);
  client.stop();
}
```

The way it's written now it cuts off the parameters in the URL with a newline, omits the "HTTP/1.1" tag at the end of the line and doesn't specify the virtual host you're trying to contact (may or may not be an issue depending on your server). It needs to send two lines to the web server, looking like:

```
GET /ethernet/data.php?movement=1 HTTP/1.1
HOST: 7751b6b1.ngrok.io
```

Comment: Hi John!

Thanks your in detail response, I wasn't aware that the ESP has trouble to connect to https server.
For simplicity I changed the server to http (since it's only for testing), now I get a connection to server, but still facing problems making the correct http request, which should be I have mentioned at the beginning of the orginal post.
I added an updated code above

Comment: @azach - not sure if Stack Overflow will notify you when I've edited an answer, but I've updated my answer with some fixes for your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still facing the same problem. Any idea what else I could do?